# How to create an encoder for array of structs in Spark SQL?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe with a field of type `ArrayType(StructType(...))`. I would like to create an aggregation function for it, but it requires the encoder for this type.

For instance for this case I have a type `array<struct<name: string, tag: string>>` and I want to aggregate this data to a `map<string, array<string>>` (the second argument is in fact a set of unique values). For this case I can do a workaround with type `array<array<string>>` where name and type are elements of the nested array. But I foresee that in scope of my task I'll meet a heterogenous structure and I can't transform it to an array without additional values transformation. And actually this way looks hideous for me.

Another way is to create a struct like `struct<data: array<struct<name: string, tag: string>>>`. And again it looks like a dirty hack.

I think there should be a way to encode arrays in Spark (at least it could create an encoder for structures with nested arrays inside). For some reasons explode is not a good solution too. It will solve this task, but it won't work for other ones. Is there any general solution?

Comment: You can create aggregate functions without types but it's not straightforward, for the most part you must provide them.  For a generic aggregate expression (or at least code example) - see here: https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/0.1.3-RC1/advanced/aggregations/#aggregation-functions